# Bootstrap CSS btn class inline and same width/size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
  <div class="row content">
  <div class="col-lg-1 sidenav"> </div>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
  <img class="img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
  <div col="col-lg-8">
  <div id="story_details" align="left" style="max-width:80%">
  <h3><?=$story_title?></h3> 
  by <a href=""><?=$author?></a>
  <br>
  <div id="genre" style="padding-top:10px;">
  <?php foreach($genre as $name){?>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-info" style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;"><?=$name?></a>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div id="total_rating">
  Gonna add stars here(4/5stars(129 ratings))
  </div>
  <div id="action" class="btn-group">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Read</a>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Add</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">


  </div>
  <div class="row">


  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 sidenav"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

I'm trying to make a profile for a story upload/read site. Simple project i'm doing to relearn php/codeigniter and explore bootstrap while i'm at it.

Here's what it looks like:
[image: Here's what it looks like]

Here's my design reference:
[image: Here's my design reference.]

My problem with the above code is that I somehow got both my buttons to be the same width but I can't get them to be on the same line.

I already tried: `<div class="btn-group inline">`

Out of frustration I've tried to just use a standard table with a single row and two divisions but that printed it below on another line `<br>`.

The `btn-block` class fulfills its purpose to even the width of the buttons but at the same time its preventing me from inlining the two buttons. If its impossible/complicated to inline `btn-blocks` then is there any other way to even the width of the two buttons?

Comment: `padding on all sides` this is called margin

Comment: `what's the limitations of bootstrap?` its very limited if you don't understand CSS and you don't read documentaiton carefully

Comment: Can you check my edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems no one can view this question because of negative and i've tried to delete this, would be a waste of a question to delete since i already got the negative marks anyway.

Here's my remedy. I'll still wait for an answer because i don't know if mine is just a hotfix or a proper one.

```
  <div id="action" class="btn-group">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-default" style="margin:2.5px 20px 2.5px 2.5px; width:150px;">Read</a>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-default" style="margin:2.5px 2.5px 2.5px 20px; width:150px;">Bookshelf</a>
  </div>
```